# Check for slave existence before running a jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

Is it possible to execute some sort of a script in a jenkins job before it starts the execution to check whether the slave exists or not ?

To avoid cluttering the jenkins queue with jobs that have non-existing nodes set to run on.

Answer (score 0):

See https://your.jenkins/computer/api/xml:

```xml
<computerSet>
  <computer>
    ...
    <offline>true</offline>
    ...
  <computer>
    ...
    <offline>true</offline>
    ...
  ...
```

or https://your.jenkins/computer/api/json:

```json
computer:
  0:
    ...
    offline: true
    ...
  1:
    ...
    offline: true
    ...
  ...
```

See http://your.jenkins/computer/api:

> You can also specify optional XPath to control the fragment you'd like to obtain (but see below). For example, `../api/xml?xpath=/*/*[0]`.